# redirecionamento com o mod_rewrite não funcionando no wamp

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

O mod_rewrite já está ativado como podemos ver em [www.joocebox.com/?phpinfo=1](http://www.joocebox.com/?phpinfo=1)

Realizei a mudança também no arquivo `httpd.conf` como abaixo:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
<Directory />
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from none
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride all
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride all
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

E finalmente criei o arquivo `.htaccess` no diretorio `"c:/wamp/www/"` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
#Ativando o mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
# Se o host for www.joocebox.com/trustbox
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}^www.joocebox.com/trustbox$ [NC]
# A regra será a seguinte
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trustbox.joocebox.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Bem, o problema é que o redirecionamento não é realizado! Retornando o erro 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal foi mais fácil do que eu pensei.

No meu `.htaccess` substitui tudo isso:

```
#Ativando o mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
# Se o host for www.joocebox.com/trustbox
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}^www.joocebox.com/trustbox$ [NC]
# A regra será a seguinte
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://trustbox.joocebox.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Por isso:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /trustbox http://trustbox.joocebox.com
```

Refência: [How to do a .htaccess 301 redirect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9pk-JCdvoM)